# Копия вордпресс сайта работает иначе

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Я создал 2 сайта.
Один работает давно.
Второй - новый, клон первого.
Я скопировал в него шаблон, папки wp-admin, wp-includes.
Но видеоплеер не отображается (точнее, его высота равна нулю)

Код старого сайта

```
<div style="width: 566px; display: block; height: 318.375px;" class="wp-video">
```

Код нового сайта

```
<div style="width: 640px; display: block;" class="wp-video">
```

Значение высоты на новом сайте отсутствует по непонятной причине. Оно меняется динамически (при изменении ширины окна), отсутствует в файлах шаблона.

Как же на новом сайте его вывести? И почему копия сайта его не отображает?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220

Comment: нет, это не миграция. это копия файлов шаблона и движка. Но не базы.

Comment: Тебе KAGGDesign и показал как НАДО делать клон, а не как ты сделал. А "без базы" - это не "клон" и  не "копия".

Answer (score 0):

Вы не пробовали переустановить WordPress? Звучит как ошибка в папке wp-includes/media. Вот похожая проблема: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136253/problem-with-height-in-video-shortcode